# Перевести код с c++ на c#

Tags: c++, c#

Помогите перевести код с C++ на C#:

```
class __declspec(uuid("EFE19EA0-09E4-11D2-A601-008048DA00DE")) IExtWndsSupport: public IUnknown{
public:
    HRESULT __stdcall GetAppMainFrame(HWND *hwnd);
    HRESULT __stdcall GetAppMDIFrame(HWND *hwnd);
    HRESULT __stdcall CreateAddInWindow(const BSTR bstrProgID, const BSTR bstrWindowName,
        int dwStyles, int dwExStyles, RECT *rctl,
        int Flags, HWND *pHwnd, IDispatch *pDisp);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Где-то так:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("EFE19EA0-09E4-11D2-A601-008048DA00DE")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IExtWndsSupport
{
    void GetAppMainFrame(
        [Out] out IntPtr hwnd);

    void GetAppMDIFrame(
        [Out] out IntPtr hwnd);

    void CreateAddInWindow(
        [In] string bstrProgID,
        [In] string bstrWindowName,
        [In] int dwStyles,
        [In] int dwExStyles,
        [In, Out] ref RECT *rctl,
        [In] int Flags,
        [In, Out] ref IntPtr pHwnd,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] ref object pDisp);
}
```

Так как по интерфейсу невозможно понять, какой аргумент на вход, а какой на выход, то сделал в общем виде. Поправьте `In`/`Out`/`In,Out`/`ref`/`out` в соответствии с реальным использованием, чтобы было удобнее.

Вообще, лучше б вы взяли TLD и воспользовались встроенными инструментами, а не ковырялись с этим вручную.

Comment: спасибо, все получилось.